# How to touch EditTextPrefences from another activity or another thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, preferences, edittextpreference

i have a setting Activity that store name , by changing the name it must first send that to my server and if its store in server successfully then it should set in the summary of my `EditTextPreference` .

everything works fine but at the end i cant touch the `EditTextPreference` to set name on it.

this method is in setting activity but called from `onPostExecute` of the `AsyncTask`

```
  public void setNewSetting(Activity activity) {
    EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) UserSettingActivity.this.findPreference(activity.getString(R.string.pref_name_key));
    name = sharedPreferences.getString(activity.getString(R.string.pref_name_key), "");
    editTextPreference.setSummary(name);
}
```

the activity is the setting activity that i passed to the `AsyncTask` and then passed to method.

my problem is here and give me a `nullPoiterException` for `EditTextPreferences`

Sorry for my bad english. 
and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

If activity is still in background, pass your `context` to `AsyncTask` and create an instance of your Settings Activity.

```
SettingsActivity settingsActivity = (SettingsActivity) context;
```

then, call the method in `onPostExecute()`

```
settingsActivity.setNewSetting();
```

And, have your `setNewSetting()` method in your SettingsActivity. It should be public and put some checks for null values.

**Method 2:**

Use an interface delegate. Create an interface:

```
 public interface TaskListener {
        void onComplete();
    }
```

Pass it to AsyncTask when you execute it, something like:

```
new MyAsyncTask(params, params, new TaskListener() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete () {

        // call setNewSetting from within SettingsActivity
    }

}).execute();
```

You get it in your AsyncTask constructer:

```
public MyAsyncTask (String params, String param2, TaskListener taskListenerDelegate) {

    this.taskListenerDelegate = taskListenerDelegate;
}
```

Call its `onComplete()` in `onPostExecute()` :

```
taskListenerDelegate.onComplete();
```

**Method 3**

Not recommended, but you can try with `startActivityForResult()` too. And, listen in `onActivityResult()` to apply changes.

Comment: thank you so much. i tried the first method and it works fine. 
i will try other methods too . you saved my time. thanks alot

Comment: how about your third method? with the asynTask we dont have any intent to use startAcrivityForResult so how we can use? @rupinderjeet

Comment: that would just come into play if you used an activity instead of AsyncTask. You will use an Activity with background handlers. But, seriously, don't do this, its dirty and more pain.